# Instantiating an exported TypeScript interface

Tags: typescript, typescript2.0

I cannot seem to find a way to strongly type a custom type outside of the module, even if the interface has been exported. Take for example this Test Module with the exported TestItem

```
module Test {

    export interface TestItem {
        one: string;
        two: string;
    }


    export class TestingClass {
        private _item: TestItem;
        constructor(private item: TestItem) {
            if (!item) {
                throw new TypeError();
            }
            this._item = item;
        }
    }

}
```

Ideally I could do something like

```
var testItem = new Test.TestItem{
    one: "Test",
    two: "Test"
};
```

This would enforce what a TestItem should look like. However currently the only way I can get it working is more like

```
var testItem = {
    one: "test",
    two: "test"
}

var testClass = new Test.TestingClass(testItem);
```

At the time of creating a TestItem outside the module, you do not necessarily know what it needs to look like. There is nothing to show the exported interface, when you do `Test.` and see the options, you only see the exported class. Is there something different about exporting interfaces in TS 2.0.5?

Comment: An interface is not an instantiable class and can only be used as type annotation, it has no runtime effect at all. `var testItem: Test.TestItem = { ... }`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to use the interface name as the **type** of a variable:

```
var testItem: Test.TestItem = {
    one: "Test",
    two: "Test"
};
```

Comment: Ah! That is what I was doing wrong! Thanks Mattias.